# Gulp compass and symbol in css content

Tags: sass, gulp, compass

I have a little issue with my ouput sass to css with gulp.
I use *gulp-compass*

and this is my code in gulpfile

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
gulp.src('css/style.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
        css: 'css/',
        sass: 'css/',
        image: 'images/',
        comments : false,
        style: 'compressed', //nested, expanded, compact, or compressed.
        time: false
        //debug: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
```

});

this script works fine, but I see a little problem from css properties *content*:

- Original scss : **content:"•"**
- Compressed css : **content:"ÔÇó"**

I don't see a setup to prevent this convertion.

Have you ever seen this result and how can I block this ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `@charset "UTF-8";` to the top of your main file with all your imports in.

Also make sure in your editor you are editing and saving the files as UTF-8

Comment: Thanks a lot it was just that ... :)